# Game of Life C++, checking neighbors

Tags: c++, conways-game-of-life

I am trying to write Conway's Game of Life.

Unfortunately, when I go to check a block's neighbors, I always receive an error at certain elements in my arrays. Specifically at `grid[0][11]` it gives me one neighbor, however, I have it set so that I only ever add value to a variable called neighbors when a block around it is not space, or `' '` in my code.

The conditions in the if statements, I believe, also account so that it does not go outside the array.

The entire array is filled with `' '`, and I still get a value to neighbor despite this.

I have been at this for hours and have found no solution. My code is still riddled with attempts to test, and I apologize for its lack of neatness. Thank you all in advance for any help you can give in solving my problem.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    bool infloop = true;
    //Create the playing grid.
    char grid[HEIGHT][WIDTH];
    //Comment out later. Used for testing.
    for(int i=0; i<75; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<22; j++)
            grid[i][j] = ' ';

    //Create initial seed here. grid [x coordinate] [y coordinate].
    //grid [1][1] = '+'; grid [2][1] = '+'; grid [3][1] = '+';

    //Key. * is going to live. + is alive currently. 
    //- is going to die, and negative space is dead.

    //As Conway's Game of Life runs infinitely, create an infinite loop.
    while (infloop)
        generation(grid);


    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void generation(char grid[][WIDTH]) {

    int neighbors;

    /*Check each point on the grid for alive or dead. If it is, check the 
    surrounding neighbors and apply the game's rules.*/
    for(int x=0; x<75; x++) {
        for(int y=0; y<22; y++)
        {

            neighbors = 0;
            /*check all eight neighbors except for when outside of the 
            array.*/
            if((grid[x+1][y] != ' ') && (grid[x+1][y] < grid[HEIGHT][y])){
                neighbors++; cout << "A";
            }

            if((grid[x-1][y] != ' ') && (grid[x-1][y] > grid[-1][y])){
                neighbors++; cout << "E";
            }

            if((grid[x][y+1] != ' ') && (grid[x][y+1] < grid[x][WIDTH])){
                neighbors++; cout << "C";
            }

            if((grid[x][y-1] != ' ') && (grid[x][y-1] > grid[x][-1])){
                neighbors++; cout << "G";
            }

            if((grid[x+1][y+1] != ' ') && (grid[x+1][y+1] < grid[HEIGHT][WIDTH])){
                neighbors++; cout << "B";
            }

            grid[0][11] = ' '; grid[11][0] = ' ';
            if((grid[x-1][y-1] != ' ') && (grid[x-1][y-1] > grid[-1][-1])){
                neighbors++; cout << "F";
            }

            if((grid[x+1][y-1] != ' ') && (grid[x+1][y] < grid[HEIGHT][y]) &&
                (grid[x][y-1] > grid[x][-1])){
                    neighbors++; cout << "H";
            }

            if((grid[x-1][y+1] != ' ') && (grid[x-1][y] > grid[-1][y])
                && (grid[x][y+1] < grid[x][WIDTH])){
                    neighbors++; cout << "D";
            }

            system("pause");

            cout << neighbors;

            //Set a marker for each point according to neighbor amounts and key.
            if(grid[x][y] == '+' && neighbors < 2)
                grid[x][y] = '-';

            if(grid[x][y] == '+' && (neighbors == 2 || neighbors == 3))
                grid[x][y] = '*';

            if(grid[x][y] == '+' && neighbors > 3)
                grid[x][y] = '-';

            if(grid[x][y] == ' ' && (neighbors == 3))
                grid[x][y] = '*';
        }
    }
    for(int x=0; x<75; x++){
        for(int y=0; y<22; y++)
        {
            if(grid[x][y] == '*')
                grid[x][y] = '+';

            if(grid[x][y] == '-')
                grid[x][y] = ' ';
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    display(grid);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an easy way to check if a cell's neighbors are alive. Place the following code in a function and pass in the row and column of the cell you wish to check.

```
int live_cell_count = 0;
for (int i = -1; i <= 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++)
    {
        //disregard grid[row][col]
        if (!(i == 0 && j == 0) && inBounds(row+i,col+j)
                 && grid[row+i][col+j] == '+')
              live_cell_count++;
    }
}
```

Note that `bool inBounds(int, int)` is a function that checks to make sure you aren't going off the array. If you were working with a 40 x 30 grid, `inBounds()` would be this simple one-liner

`return ((row >= 0 && row < 40) && (col >= 0 && col < 30));`

I leave it as an exercise to the OP to apply the rules of life based on the value of `live_cell_count`

Answer (score 1):

The neighbor checking is currently checking the *contents* when you want to be checking the *index*.  Also, make sure you check the index *before* you check the contents, or you will get array out of bounds problems.

Here's the first one fixed:

```
if ((x+1 < HEIGHT) && (grid[x+1][y] != ' ')) { // Swap and index instead of contents.
   neighbors++; cout << "A";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`75` is better to be replaced by `HEIGHT`, `22` replaced by `WIDTH`.

```
if((grid[x+1][y] != ' ') && (x+1 < HEIGHT)) {
        neighbors++; cout<<"A";
}
```

should be

```
if((x+1 < HEIGHT) && (grid[x+1][y] != ' ')) { // The range check should be done firstly
        neighbors++; cout<<"A";
}
```